# The emulator process for AVD Nexus_5X_API_30 was killed

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-11

Firstly, I want to say that I looked into all the solutions in here and on the net but couldn't resolve the issue.

My system properties : 16GB RAM, Intel Core i7-7700HQ CPU 2.80ghz and 64-bit version of Windows 10.

The virtual device I'm trying to use : Nexus 5X API 30, Android 11.0, arm64/x86 for CPU/ABI.

When I'm trying to start android-studio emulator this error(in the title) pops up. What I've done so far is:

1. I installed Android Studio to C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio and after that I installed SDK's to E:\Android-SDK folder because my default path C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk has non-ascii characters and space because of my username.
2. I changed the values of environment variables ANDROID_HOME and ANDROID_SDK_ROOT to E:\Android-SDK
3. I have 16GB RAM and  enough memory for both C and E disks (40gb and 140gb respectively.). I'm not facing any issues while executing the program, just the emulator doesn't work properly and nothing appears in the Event Log (can be seen in below).

Lastly, while I was searching for the solution I noticed that all of the people who are suffering from this error have a common ground that is they're using non-ascii characters because of their alphabet. Android studio doesn't allow you to use non-ascii characters in the file path. As I mentioned above my SDK paths are not the default for this reason. So the error might be caused by this.

Comment: You should always add in TEXT of any error you have. The fact that the CPU/ABI of your emulator image is `arm64` is odd as it should be `x86`. Please review [Emulator Acceleration](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration#accel-vm) and make sure you have HAXM installed. Then create a new AVD of the x86 type and see if that runs.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I edited the question accordingly. I have HAXM installed, now I will review the document you posted thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who have the same issue with me, after a long investigation i found that my SDK and AVD paths were broken. The Android Studio only says "process killed" and in the event log there was nothing. I was sure that the issue wasn't about my system requirements so I ran the Emulator from command prompt to see the detailed error and the error was "**PANIC: Broken AVD system path. Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT value**". After that I set the Environment Variables for ANDROID_SDK_ROOT and ANDROID_AVD_HOME (You can see the detailed instructions from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/variables)). Then I created a new virtual device (this is IMPORTANT because the old devices was still using the old paths.) and my issue is resolved. I wrote my solution here for everyone to see because the issue took to much effort to resolve it.